# Errors in std_logic vector increment

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a project where I am walking through a BRAM.  I have an issue in one of the parts where I increment the address. I duplicated the logic I am using in the below state machine. Please point out my error here my increment is erratic and doesn't happen as expected.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity test is
  port (clk   : in  std_logic;
        count : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        reset : in  std_logic);
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is
  signal c : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  type state_type is (state1, state2, state3, state4);
  signal gcd_cs, gcd_ns : state_type;
begin
  count <= c;
  process(clk, reset, c)
  begin
    if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
      if(reset = '1')then
        gcd_cs <= state1;
      else
        gcd_cs <= gcd_ns;
      end if;
    end if;
    case gcd_cs is
      when state1 =>
        if(reset = '0') then
          gcd_cs <= state2;
        else
          gcd_cs <= state1;
        end if;
      when state2 =>
        if(c > "0000001111") then
          gcd_cs <= state4;
        else
          gcd_cs <= state3;
        end if;
      when state3 =>
        c      <= c+'1';
        gcd_ns <= state2;
      when state4 =>
        gcd_ns <= state4;
    end case;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You appear to be using signals as if they were variables.  They aren't the same at all.

Comment: Hello i also tried changing the count to a variable still no result. can you suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of problems here.

1. Your counter/state update logic is not synchronized to a clock (it's outside the `IF clk'event`)
2. You are using signals as if they were variables.
3. Your expressions are sensitive to variables not in the sensitivity list.
4. Your case statement outputs sometimes the current state and sometimes the next state.

Pay attention to compiler warnings about latches, sensitivity lists, etc.

Change your next-state calculation to concurrent logic.  The process should only update signals which are registers (D flip-flops, basically).

Something like this:

```
PROCESS (clk,reset)
BEGIN
    IF reset = '1' THEN
        gcd_cs <= state1; -- for asynchronous reset
        c <= (OTHERS => '0');
    ELSIF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
        IF reset = '1' THEN
            gcd_cs <= state1; -- for synchronous reset
            c <= (OTHERS => '0');
        ELSE
            IF gcd_cs = state3 THEN
                 c <= c + 1;
            END IF;
            gcd_cs <= gcd_ns;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

gcd_ns <= state2 WHEN gcd_cs = state1 ELSE
          state4 WHEN gcd_cs = state2 AND c > "0000001111" ELSE
          state3 WHEN gcd_cs = state2 AND NOT (c > "0000001111") ELSE
          state2 WHEN gcd_cs = state3 ELSE
          state4 WHEN gcd_cs = state4;
```

Pick only one of the two reset behaviors.